# Как создается дистрибутив для программы на с++?

Tags: c++, установка

Допустим я написал ПО и хочу чтобы оно село на другой ПК, что мне делать?
Может у кого есть ссылка на крутую статью где все хорошо расписано, бикоз я ничего не нашел нормального.

Comment: уточните ОС (виндовс/линукс/андроид...)

Comment: @goldstar_labs Windows

Comment: В MCVS есть специальный проект по созданию msi. Там ты выбираешь файлы, может редактировать окна или сделать вообще что-то своё.